# Two manos of meat

Tags: halacha, food, purim, meat, mishloach-manot

The Rambam says that one can give "two portions (*manos*) of meat" as mishloach manos. The Aruch Hashulchan 695:14 explains the Rambam should read "two *types* (*minim*) of meat":

> וברור הדבר דצריך לשלוח שני מיני אוכלין, או שני מיני משקין, או מין אוכל ומין משקה. והכי איתא להדיא בגמרא (ז א) דאחד שלח לחבירו בשר ויין, עיין שם. אבל שני חתיכות ממין אחד – אינו מועיל. דכי מפני שחתכן נחשבם לשנים?
>   והרמב"ם כתב: וכן חייב לשלוח שתי מנות בשר, או שני מיני אוכלין, או שני מיני תבשיל, עיין שם. הרי שכתב שני מינים, ובעל כרחך צריך לומר דזה שכתב "שתי מנות בשר" – היינו משני מיני בשר. או אפשר דטעות הדפוס הוא, וכן צריך לומר: "שני מיני בשר כמו שני מיני אוכלין...".‏

Are sweetbread and a steak from the same cow considered two types of meat according to this Aruch Hashulchan?

Comment: Why do you think being from the same cow would matter?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35541

Answer (score 2):

[Nitei Gavriel Purim 58:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46446&st=&pgnum=325&hilite=) brings in the name of the Rosh Yosef and others that by meat it is 2 portions so long they are from different parts of the animal, since they have different tastes. He brings from the [Shaalos U'Teshuvos Sheeris Yehuda 93](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1890&pgnum=173) that it can even be from the same part of the animal so long it is 2 portions

It seems to me from the language of the Aruch Hashulchan that he would disagree with both of these Shittos, and it would have to be two different types of meat, similar to two types of food.

Comment: "and it would have to be different types of meat" isn't really any clearer than "Shnei Minei Basar". Do you mean two different cows, two different parts of the same cow, two different species of animal?

Comment: Rav Shmuel Kamenestky holds that the top of and bottom of a chicken only counts for one.Rav Shlomo Zalman holds it does count for two.Thats why not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, kind of hard to answer properly, citing sources specific enough to your question, but I believe the answer is yes, that's exactly what the RaMBa"M means - two distinct pieces of meat (as opposed to one steak that's been cut in two). "Why?" is a different question. But for purposes of this question, I think it should suffice to say that two different cuts of meat should satisfy the RaMBa"M's requirement, even according to the 'Aruch HaShulhan.

Having said that, it might be that the 'Aruch HaShulhan *prefers* that you provide meat from a cow and meat from a lamb (or something), but I don't think he's saying that's necessarily the *only* way to satisfy "Shnei Minei Basar".