# Two minim for Mishloach Manos?

Tags: halacha, purim, mishloach-manot

What is the earliest source for requiring two minim (types of food) for Mishloach Manos? The Rambam (Hil. Megillah 2:15) only requires two portions. (See Aruch HaShulchan 695:14) 
I know a rabbi who takes issue with the two minim, and only requires two portions. Are there any early sources who require two types of food?

Comment: The Gra in Maaseh Rav

Comment: Did the Gra do  it or require it?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26441. And similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6325.

Comment: Are there any later sources who require two minim? What does "minim" even mean here?

Comment: @DoubleAA,Yes. The aruch hashulchan that I referenced requires it. What do you mean by "what does minim even mean here?"?

Comment: Ish, according to the _AHS_, the _Rambam_ requires two _minim_: quite an early source. Is that an acceptable answer?

Comment: @msh210, No. That is an odd reading of the Rambam. From the Rambam we see that two minim is also acceptable.